# Detectar cuando cambia el tamaño de la pantalla con Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy haciendo una clase, que, debería retornarme si la pantalla del usuario se redimensiona.

**responsive.ts**

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MediaMatcher } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

export default class ResponsiveDevice implements OnDestroy {

    private query: MediaQueryList;
    private listener: () => void;

    constructor( media?: MediaMatcher, change?: ChangeDetectorRef ) {
        this.query = media.matchMedia(' (max-width:600px) ');
        this.listener = () => change.detectChanges();
        this.query.addEventListener( 'change', this.listener );
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.query.removeEventListener( 'change', this.listener );
    }

    isMobile(): boolean {
        return this.query.matches;
    }
}
```

Así la puedo invocar desde cualquier pantalla que necesite saber el tamaño de la pantalla y decidir funcionalidades.

**cover.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import ResponsiveDevice from '../../global/functions/responsive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cover',
  templateUrl: './cover.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cover.component.scss']
})
export class CoverComponent implements OnInit {

  isMobile: boolean;
  form: FormGroup;
  options: string[] = ['Ciudad de México', 'Puebla', 'Baja California'];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      search: new FormControl( null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)] )
    });
    const responsive = new ResponsiveDevice();
    this.isMobile    = responsive.isMobile();
  }

}
```

Pero cuando inicializa la pantalla me salta este error.

```
core.js:6228 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'matchMedia' of undefined
    at new ResponsiveDevice (responsive.ts:10)
    at CoverComponent.ngOnInit (cover.component.ts:21)
    at callHook (core.js:4726)
    at callHooks (core.js:4690)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:4630)
    at refreshView (core.js:12013)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13445)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11716)
    at refreshView (core.js:12051)
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (core.js:12129)
```

Evidentemente `media` no está definido, pero no debería mandar error, pues es el `constructor` el que la declara y la usa.

Me base en [este ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/aalmbedopkvr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.ts) para intentar refactorizar la función. Utilizo Angular 9.

Comment: ¿Por qué injectas el `MediaMatcher` de forma opcional?

Comment: Por que si lo dejo requerido al instanciar del otro lado me la pide, y la intención es que todo se haga ahí.

Comment: Si no creas la instancia pasándole ningún parámetro, obviamente `media` va a ser `undefined` siempre. Sería mejor que registrarlas el `ResponsiveDevice` como servicio, con `MediaMatcher` y `ChangeDetectorRef` como sus dependencias e inyectaras este servicio en los componentes que lo requieran, sin tener que preocuparse de instanciar el servicio.

Comment: existe el evento onresize, haz intentado usarlo?

Comment: Si @Riven, pero siguiendo las buenas prácticas de Angular, procuro no tocar directamente el DOM.

Comment: Comprenderia que para aplicaciones moviles no seria optimo usar las referencias a la ventana, pero en caso que tu app de angular sea para la web, no creo que sea malo usar la referencia a la ventana, si bien deben haber metodos en angular especializados en ello usar la ventana de verdad generaria conflictos?, creo que no hay que discriminar a las partes nativas de javascript y html, puesto que de todas maneras angular tiene su propia version de la ventana.

Answer (score 0):

Haz intentado con

```
import { BreakpointObserver } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

const oritentation = this.breakObsrv.observe([
      '(max-width: 599px)',
      '(orientation: portrait)',
      '(orientation: landscape)',
    ]);
    oritentation.subscribe(lay => {
      this.Landscape = lay.breakpoints[('(orientation: landscape)')];
    });
```

Mas info [Aqui](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview)